# VBA “Compile Error: Statement invalid outside Type Block” for variables

Tags: vba, excel

I want to use a global variable (`cmb`) in a function (`CommandButton2_Click`) to copy columns from one workbook to another using VBA. 
This is my code:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim cmb As String

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Cell As Range, rng As Range, sht As Worksheet
    Set cmb = Form.ComboBox1.Value
    Set sht = wb.Worksheets(cmb)
    'assuming your headers are always on the first row...
    Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Range("A1"), _
                        sht.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))

    'add some code here to clear the lists first!...
    For Each Cell In rng.Cells
        If Len(Cell.Value) > 0 Then
            Form.ComboBox2.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox3.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox4.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox5.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox6.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox7.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox8.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox9.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox10.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox11.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox12.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox13.AddItem (Cell.Value)
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim sFilePath As String
    sFilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath)
    For Each sht In wb.Worksheets
          Form.ComboBox1.AddItem sht.Name
    Next sht
End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    'Copy Column from one workbook to another
    Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range
    Set sourceColumn = wb.Worksheets(cmb).Columns(Form.ComboBox2.Value)
    Set targetColumn = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Columns("PART NUMBER")
    sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
End Sub
```

I'm getting a `Compile Error: Statement invalid outside Type Block`error at `Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()`. I wonder why though. I have declared the variable `cmb` as global. Why is the variable not in scope?

Comment: You are not setting wb `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath)`

Comment: You also do not `set` a string variable `Set cmb = ..` should only be `cmb = ...`

Comment: And you are missing the keyword `Dim` on `Cell As Range, rng As Range, sht As Worksheet`

Comment: @danieltakeshi *cough* except `Let` is just as obsolete as `Rem`, `Global` and `Call` and `On Local Error` ...why carry 20-year obsolete syntax into this century?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it has to be:

```
Public wb as Workbook
Public cmb as String
```

and:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim Cell As Range, rng As Range, sht As Worksheet
```

Comment: I made that change, and then I'm thrown an error (`Run Time Error 13: Type Mismatch`) at `Set sourceColumn = wb.Worksheets(cmb).Columns(Form.ComboBox2.Value)`. What could this be?

Comment: @user248884 I know: it's *another completely unrelated question* - mark this one as accepted (click the hollow green checkmark) and post a [mcve] specifically about the new error in a new post.

Comment: @user248884 Even better, ask Google about assigning columns to variables in Excel VBA, then ask questions if you have difficulties.

Comment: @VictorK Cool. Thanks!